# C# Fill Datagridview in Form1 using Form2 query button

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, button, datagridview

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SERVER CONNECTION//
        GLOBALDCC_Home globaldcchome = new GLOBALDCC_Home();
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);

        //QUERY//
        string sorgu = "select * " + "from dcc.db";

        MySqlCommand database = new MySqlCommand(sorgu, connection);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = database;
        DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dbdataset);
        globaldcchome.dataGridView1.DataSource = dbdataset;
        da.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: please show us your code what you have and what you have tried also, then we can help you

Comment: Hi Simon Thanks your kind response, I will send at evening now i am at work.If you have time could you mentioned a little bit how to.

Comment: Shortly I want to control datagridview which is in main form , from other form.

Comment: have you actually tried anything yourself yet?  if so please post your code

Comment: Hi  Simon I added the code.

Comment: the question has been locked so I cant offer an answer but where you have your code for the datasource, all you need to do is something like this `Form1.dataGridView1.DataSource = dbdataset` and then bind the data and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Add a public method on Form2:

```
 public void AddDataToGrid(Object data)
 {
     // Add data to the grid

 }
```